# row and column spans in recycler gridlayout manager

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, gridlayoutmanager

I have this layout that I want to create with the same column and row spans for each grid item and my activity has a *RecyclerView* with a *GridLayoutManager*.

Can you please give me advice on fixing the column and row span for each item in the adapter?

Here's the layout:

[image: image link]

Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently you have a mix of items that span both rows and columns.  My understanding about `GridLayoutManager` is that you can span columns for vertical orientation and rows for horizontal orientation, but not both at the same time.

I would recommend that you look at `GridLayout` instead.  `GridLayout` allows you to span both rows and columns.  It just doesn't use an adapter the way `RecyclerView` does.

You may also be able to find some custom `RecyclerView` layout managers on GitHub that allow spans in both directions.

Comment: I didn't get what you mean by GridLayout? Can you provide some example about your solution?

Comment: @PeerNet See https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout.html also https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-user-interface-design-creating-a-numeric-keypad-with-gridlayout--mobile-8677 or google "android gridlayout" for more examples.

Comment: I know what gridlayout is but how to use it with recycler view? I am implementing tile view creating same view(rectangle) with different picture. So I have just recycler view and it's item as layout